# Play audio from javascript in HTML5 WITHOUT a file - using buffer

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, audio

I'm using jQuery's ajax method to call a PHP script on the server which will return an mp3 file to me, so I have the data in a variable to the success function.  Now I want to play that audio for the person.  I am using HTML5, but every example I've seen expects you to point at a file that has the audio.  I don't have it as a file, I have it in memory.

Comment: Why return the MP3 data via AJAX?  Why not let the browser handle it for you, specifying the URL of your PHP script for that media?  It would be far more efficient and compatible that way.  Other methods involve putting it into a Blob, or using the Web Audio API with a script node.

Comment: Because the PHP script being called expects a POST with multiple parameters.

Comment: I would do your `POST` (assuming you're actually changing data) separately and return a token that you can then call your video script with a normal `GET`.  This is a far better solution.

Comment: The mp3 file is dynamically created based on the contents sent to the php script and returned to the browser.  I'm not sure how what you're saying would actually work.

Comment: Write a temporary file to disk and return an ID that references that file as a response to your AJAX POST.  You could either use a sufficiently long ID so that this file can exist in the document root, or do something like `getMp3File.php?id=0123456789abcdef`.  Not only will this vastly increase browser support and greatly enhance performance, but you will automatically add support for seeking in the file with range requests.

Comment: I know I'm being dense here, sorry.  I modified my php file to use a GET instead of a POST.  When I click my button the javascript method is called which pulls the values to send to the php script.  How do I actually 'call' it at that point if I'm not doing an ajax call?  I don't want the current page to change when I do this as there are form elements filled out already.

Comment: All you have to do at that point is append an audio element.  Something like `$('body').append($('<audio>').attr('src', 'yourScript.php?' + yourQueryString));`

Answer (score 2):

Here is something to get you started using the Web Audio API. `theAjaxResponse` should be the mp3 response, in binary, from the server.

```
window.AudioContext = window.AudioContext || window.webkitAudioContext;
var context = new AudioContext();

context.decodeAudioData(theAjaxResponse, function(buffer) {
      var source = context.createBufferSource();
      source.buffer = buffer;
      source.connect(context.destination);
      source.start(0);
}, onError);
```

This will only work in modern browsers supporting the Web Audio API.

Comment: I'm getting back a syntax error when I try that on the decodeAudioData line.

Comment: OK, found I had to convert theAjaxResponse into an ArrayBuffer before it can go here.  Now i'm getting back a null error though that I have to track down.